# ¿Cómo funciona ADD COLUMN con AFTER para varias columnas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla en cuya estructura quiero insertar varias columnas nuevas.

Mi tabla está más o menos así ahora, estás son las columnas:

```
...
vi_meta
vi_himno
vi_salmos
vi_lecturas
vi_oracion
...<-------------seguir insertando aquí
id_color
id_tiempo
```

Ahora yo quiero insertar, después de `vi_oracion`, las columnas

```
co_meta
co_himno
co_salmos
co_lecturas
co_oracion
```

Para insertar una sola columna yo hago esto:

```
ALTER TABLE `liturgia`
ADD COLUMN `co_meta` CHAR(10) AFTER `vi_oracion`
```

Lo que quiero saber es si puedo insertar sin riesgo varias columnas al mismo tiempo, o sea, a mi sentencia de más arriba agregarle las otras columnas que quiero insertar y que la tabla quede así:

```
...
vi_meta
vi_himno
vi_salmos
vi_lecturas
vi_oracion

co_meta
co_himno
co_salmos
co_lecturas
co_oracion

id_color
id_tiempo
...
```

Comment: te comento que deacuerdo a la propia documentación de MySQL indica que es posible, te adjunto la sintáxis y al menos revisando no veo que marque alguna advertencia https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

Comment: @AlfredoPaz no sé si los `ADD COLUMN` trabajan en cadena. Mi duda es  ¿si pongo otros `ADD COLUMN` en la misma sentencia reconocerá que la columna anterior ya ha sido creada?... No quiero que me estropee la tabla, porque ya tiene datos.

Comment: te comento que acabo de hacer un pequeño ejercicio añadiendo columnas a una tabla con datos ya existente y no los eliminó, ahí se mantuvieron pero no se como mostrarte el jemplo

Comment: crees que sirva si lo pongo como respuesta y tu lo pruebas en uan base de datos de ejemplo?

Comment: En efecto, he hecho una prueba en una tabla creada para ese propósito y me ha funcionado bien de esta manera: `ALTER TABLE liturgia
ADD COLUMN co_meta CHAR(10) AFTER vi_oracion,
ADD COLUMN co_kirye CHAR(10) AFTER co_meta,
ADD COLUMN co_himno CHAR(10) AFTER co_kirye,
ADD COLUMN co_salmos CHAR(10) AFTER co_himno,
ADD COLUMN co_biblica CHAR(10) AFTER co_salmos,
ADD COLUMN co_oracion CHAR(10) AFTER co_biblica,
ADD COLUMN co_virgen CHAR(10) AFTER co_oracion;` Puedes ponerlo como respuesta, indicando algo de la documentación si lo ves oportuno.

Comment: hecho esta espero sirva de algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder agregar mas columnas en una posición en específico debemos hacerlo en orden de procedencia, del modo siguiente

```
ALTER TABLE den
ADD COLUMN co_meta char(10) AFTER var2,
ADD COLUMN co_datos char(10) AFTER co_meta;
```

> Donde como se nota después de agregar la columna co_meta en la
>   siguiente instrucción co_datos indico que va después de co_meta
>   (aclaracióin var2 es la primera y única columna que estaba declarada
>   por defecto antes de agregar mas por eso le indico que co_meta va
>   después de ella)

```
CREATE DATABASE jemplo;

USE jemplo;

CREATE TABLE den(
 var1 varchar(100),
 var2 varchar(200)
);

insert into den(var1, var2) values("h", "h"),("j", "d");
```

Si aquí hago un select me devuelve lo siguiente

```
+------+------+
| var1 | var2 |
+------+------+
| h    | h    |
| j    | d    |
+------+------+

ALTER TABLE den
ADD COLUMN co_meta char(10) AFTER var2,
ADD COLUMN co_datos char(10) AFTER co_meta;
```

Después de hacer el agregado de columnas, obtengo lo siguiente

```
+------+------+---------+----------+
| var1 | var2 | co_meta | co_datos |
+------+------+---------+----------+
| h    | h    | NULL    | NULL     |
| j    | d    | NULL    | NULL     |
+------+------+---------+----------+
```

Donde como se puede notar se mantienen los datos ingresados anteriormente

La documentación de MySQL nos muestra que para agregar múltiples columnas es mejor invocar a ADD COLUMN por cada columna nueva [aquí la referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)